# Local host is not comming up on android emulator

Tags: node.js, android-emulator

I have been trying to run my app on android emulator and send requests to my node js local host but localhost:3000 is not working in emulator i also tried 10.0.2.2 and 10.0.3.2 im using Andy android Emulator and my server is up on windows localhost:3000 works on windows but nothing works in the emulator what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution:
first you should run ipconfig command than there is an ip in one of of the adapters that it bring ,in front of the ipv4 ,mine was 192.168.1.4 you should that ip with :3000 then you can access your local host.
I was using Nox app player

Comment: i did not even think about it, but once i check my ip, and used that in a virtual device it worked. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this ?

```
10.0.2.2:3000
```

this should work.
if this is not working check that you're server is up and running on port 3000

Comment: try this site 
https://www.whatismyip.com/
its gonna show you you're ip, try to use this